# How do I stop Azure Data Factory escaping double quotes with \

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a lookup activity within Azure Data Factory pipeline, it returns the output of a concatenated string from a stored procedure;

```
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', id, '"'), ',') AS id
FROM #processedRecords;
```

This returns an output like below;

```
"0xE86B6656CA08E3B7AC704ECFC0F9A1B5086DF3461EE446999C523710AFB31888","0x6109C57BEBAE6BE14E4955E51B076E72A6FE5E0251D7043E5721020676B9CA6D","0x1E17C7C700468FD08D3F020CAF100C9A60D843A4D3FCCA726A07AFAD77AC825A"
```

When I run the lookup activity in ADF, it outputs the below;

```
{
    "firstRow": {
        "id": "\"0xE86B6656CA08E3B7AC704ECFC0F9A1B5086DF3461EE446999C523710AFB31888\",\"0x6109C57BEBAE6BE14E4955E51B076E72A6FE5E0251D7043E5721020676B9CA6D\",\"0x1E17C7C700468FD08D3F020CAF100C9A60D843A4D3FCCA726A07AFAD77AC825A\""
```

How can I stop it escaping the double quotes, so that it does not contain the backslash ().

I have tried a replace in a set variable like so;

```
@replace(activity('Lookup JSON').output.firstRow.id,'\' , '')
```

But it still escapes the double quote?

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, by default it will add the `backslash(\)` for string as escape character for `double quote(")`. But it won't part of the string when we store this string in any of the file from ADF and it won't be a problem while working on string operations in ADF.

For demonstration purpose, I have tried the same scenario, and this is my lookup output:

[image]

I have stored the **length of this above string which had backslashes** in a variable using the below expression.

```
@string(length(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].id))
```

[image]

**Length of the same string without backslashes(\):**

```
@string(length('"0xE86B6656CA08E3B7AC704ECFC0F9A1B5086DF3461EE446999C523710AFB31888","0x6109C57BEBAE6BE14E4955E51B076E72A6FE5E0251D7043E5721020676B9CA6D","0x1E17C7C700468FD08D3F020CAF100C9A60D843A4D3FCCA726A07AFAD77AC825A"'))
```

[image]

You can see lengths of both are same and that means in ADF both strings are same.

It(**backslash(\)**) won't be replaced because it's not present in string but ADF just adds it by default as an escape character. You can use the lookup output string like a normal string as per your requirement.